# How to find the path of least sum, moving right and down in a binary matrix

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, language-agnostic

I have a binary matrix. Each column corresponds to a vertex in a graph. If I walk along the path (starting on the "col 1" vertex, then moving on to "col 2" etc.), I have to pay some fines. But since there are only so many police officers on the path, I can wait for some time until there is no police officer remaining on the next vertex, then go over. To clarify, the following matrix (first row is the "title" row):

```
A B C D
0 0 1 0
1 0 0 1
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
```

Encodes that I will pay if I am on A after waiting an extra 1, 2 or 3 hours before that point; on B, I will pay after 2 or 3 extra hours; on C, I will pay after 0 or 3 hours; on D, I will pay if I wait 1 or 3 hours.

As such, the optimal path here is "move to B, wait 1 hour, move to C, wait 1 hour, move to D", with total cost 0. (this path is marked with "X" on the following)

```
A B C D
X X 1 0
1 X X 1
1 1 X X
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
```

However, achieving 0 is not always possible, and I am only interested in one of the paths of minimal sum that goes from the top left entry to the right column.

How can I generate such a path efficiently?

The naive algorithm "generate all paths, find the minimum" works in exponential time, which doesn't feel optimal to me.

I thought of using a DP approach, but I was unable to formulate one that did not break on some cases, whether I try to add line-by-line or column-by-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a simple question. Let's say you're at row `i`, column `j` (i.e. cell `(i,j)`) of the matrix. What choices do you have for the next step?

Since we're moving column-wise, `j` becomes `j+1`. But for the row, you can greedily choose the row which pays the minimum fine. That is, you can pick `i'` in range `(i+1, row_count)` such that `fine(i,j)` is minimum. (Note: since the row represents points in time, you can't go from row `i` to `i-1`, effectively shortening our search space).

The algorithm:
(`n = number of rows = len(matrix)`, `m = number of columns`)

1. For the rightmost column, we don't have any further paths, so no modification needed
2. For columns `m-1 to 1`, the minimum fine for cell `(i,j)` will be

```
fine(i,j) = (matrix[i][j] == 1) + (min_value in matrix[i][j+1] to matrix[n][j+1])
```

3. Min path cost will be `matrix[0][0]`, from where you trace the path by checking the min values from each column.

The last point we need to cover is, how to get `min_value in matrix[i][j+1] to matrix[n][j+1]` in step 2? If you traverse from `row n` to `row 1`, the task basically boils down to keeping a track of the smallest element visited yet, which can be done using a simple variable/counter.

The approach requires no extra space (since we modify the given matrix), and `O(M*N)` time complexity.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I do not think this works.
Suppose our matrix is:
0100
0011
The optimal path moves left-to-right without ever waiting (total cost 1), but a greedy algorithm waits for an hour at vertex 1 before moving to vertices 2,3, then 4, with total cost 2.

Comment: @Kemonius no, the greedy algorithm does go left to right with cost 1, since `cost[0][1] = 1` and `cost[1][1] = 2`

Comment: Ah my mistake, I didn't see the right-to-left bit. Thanks for your answer!